# SBT compiles source files regardless of the time stamp

Tags: scala, sbt

I observed SBT compiles all source files everytime when I issue the "compile" task, regardless of time stamps since the last compile. The following is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "HelloSbt"

scalaVersion := "2.8.2"

unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := List(file("src"))
```

The following is my project structure (ignored project and target directories):

```
./src
./src/Hello1.scala
./src/a
./src/a/Hello2.scala
./build.sbt
```

The two source files are just empty object definitions for test purpose.

When I type in "sbt compile", I got the following information:

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to...
```

and I can find newly compiled class files in target directory.

Without modifying any source file, after a minute, typing "sbt compile" again I got the same info and class files, except the time stamp of class files are up to date. I was expecting the second compile would not find any modified source file and no compilation should happen.

I did the test in both Windows 7 and Debian. During the test, I didn't have any editor open. Can some one give some hint about how to setup a customized src directory while still be able to only compile modified files since last build?

Thanks

Comment: Not in the answer, but I'd open an issue about it. I think at least a warning is warranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using a relative path as if it were an absolute path. I'm surprised it even produces a result, but, anyway, you should write it like this:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <<= baseDirectory(base => List(base / "src"))
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. BTW, where can I find information like this? The original question seemed to be a trivial and fair request but I just couldn't get it right. I spent a lot of time (at least more than what I anticipated) in learning SBT but feel it is hard to bend SBT according to my needs.

Comment: Hi Daniel, could you confirm my observation: in testing the modified file compilation, I used "touch" to update file time stamp. But it seemed updated time stamp is not enough to trigger a recompilation. I need to make the source file different to trigger a recompilation. It's all ok but seems over-killing for a build tool because this means SBT has to store at least some finger print for each source file while time stamp should work for most of the time. What's the design decision behind it? (I am just interested.)

Comment: @Codism You may turn both comments into questions -- mention your two previous questions and the specific issues in the first case to avoid making the question too open-ended. The answer won't fit on comments, and, besides, it might be useful to others. And it might get better answers than what I can give.

Comment: @Codism Your questions have helped me get started with SBT, THanks!! On the file-contents-checksumming thing, SCons does the same and the idea there is that (among others) time stamps may not be so valid in certain networked scenarios. SCons gives a choice on using either time stamps, contents, or both.

Comment: @akauppi: that sounds like a valid reason. Thanks for the update.